# Upload Image to google cloud storage using iOS?

Tags: ios, google-cloud-storage

i need a help to upload image to google cloud storage using iOS ?
Please help.

Comment: Please give some more details about your question.

Comment: i am using google cloud storage for uploading images of my project. but i am not able to upload image to cloud storage through iOS code. so can you please help me for it?

Comment: Did you check that : https://medium.com/google-cloud/uploading-to-google-cloud-storage-from-ios-app-e9f4097b516#.14x1py5wr

Comment: thanks for link . i have used iOS code provided by above link, but it is showing 500 internal error after calling that method.

Answer (score 0):

This is a link for [demo](https://github.com/google/google-api-objectivec-client). You can use [google console](https://cloud.google.com/console). First, you need to enable [JSON API](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/) from above [console](https://cloud.google.com/console).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. but i have already used demo but many files are missing there . also my json API is already enable.we are able to upload image through Android but not from iOS for a now as we are not getting exact code . please assist me for it

Comment: @tejashreemahadik did you used pod?

Comment: i am not using pod